# If the conjugacy class is preserved under product.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $ G $ is a finite group. Assume that $ a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\in G $ such that $ a_1=ga_2g^{-1} $ and $ b_1=hb_2h^{-1} $ for $ g,h\in G $. I want to ask if $ a_1b_1 $ and $ a_2b_2 $ are in the same conjugacy class, i.e. there exists $ c\in G $ such that $ a_1b_1=ca_2b_2c^{-1} $.

I find that this problem can be reduced to the case that $ b_1=b_2 $. However I do not know how to go on, can you give me some hints or references?

Comment: If you don't know how "to go on", then you can try to find a counterexample. This often works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample in $S_4$: $a_1=(12), a_2=(13)$ and $b_1=(1234), b_2=(1432)$: $a_1b_1=(234), a_2b_2=(14)(23)$, and these elements have different cycle type hence not conjugate.

Comment: Again, I am downvoted. Why??

Comment: It seems fine to me (+1).

Comment: Thanks @Shaun. Someone thought the opposite.. never mind.